# How to make this Select parallel?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query which takes significantly longer (in the larger context) when run with a `Distinct()` but this (partly for legacy reasons) is inescapable.

This line runs fine, but in some instances returns duplicates, which we need to avoid:

```
memberships.AsParallel().Select(x => x.Name)
```

And I would like to put this on it:

```
memberships.AsParallel().Select(x => x.Name).Distinct()
```

But this is incredibly slow. I have tried:

```
memberships.AsParallel().Select(x => x.Name).AsParallel().Distinct()
```

But this provided no improvement.

Is there any way I can improve the performance of getting a distinct list here?

Comment: What does it mean "in the larger context"? It is EF? Maybe you have to improve your LINQ query instead of paralleling something?

Comment: Have you tried it without .AsParallel()? The Distinct() may have some sync overhead which could slow down your program

Comment: Distinct and Parallel do not run in the same amount of time.  Distinct requires you to wait for all results while parallel will return partial results before all the parallel results are received.  As they say :"You can't have your cake and pie too".  You want parallel results to save time but only want distinct.  You want to ignore duplicate results after the first is received.  So you may need to check if a results was already received so you can throw away the duplicates.

Comment: Maybe insert the values in parallel into a `ConcurrentDictionary`?

Comment: Removing the `.AsParallel()` worked. Thank you @Darem

Comment: Good to hear, thanks for the feedback